# How did 'sequester' shift semantically from 'follow' to 'remove'?

Tags: etymology

> [[ Etymonline for 'sequester (v.)' ]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sequestrate&searchmode=none) late 14c., "remove" something, "quarantine, isolate" (someone); "excommunicate;" also intransitive, "separate oneself from,"
>   from Old French *sequestrer* (14c.), from Late Latin *sequestrare* "to place in safekeeping,"
>   from Latin *sequester* "trustee, mediator," noun use of an adjective meaning **"intermediate,"** which probably is related to ***sequi* "to follow"** (see [sequel](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sequel&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>    Meaning "seize by authority, confiscate" is first attested 1510s. ...

The bolded confuses me the most.
How did **"to follow"** shift semantically to mean **"intermediate"**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is abbreviated from Robert Ainsworth’s Latin Dictionary 1783. (emphasis mine)
The development from ‘follow’ to ‘hand over’ had already taken place in classical times: so the precise etymon is **sequestro**.

A/ **sequor** as you say means to follow, 1 to pursue 2 hunt; but also 3 to follow a leader, **follow your parents**,  5 **trust, obey**… 6…

B/ **sequester  -i** or **–is**  is someone trusted by both parties, 1 an umpire 2 an arbitrator. trusted  by both parties with the sum under arbitration (Plautus) [but even Cicero uses sequester 3,4 to mean a fixer, a corrupter.]

C/ **sequestro**  adverb.  *pecuniam ponere sequestro*; to give up to arbitration,  to put the money into the umpire’s hand.

You would have to be very cynical to believe it was lost at that stage...

Answer (score 1):

[This post from http://www.spanishetymology.com](http://www.spanishetymology.com/seguir-and-sequester/) dated 2015/12/28 aided me to understand the semantic shifts. I omit blockquotes to ease readability.

---

[Seguir](http://www.spanishetymology.com/seguir-persecute-sequel/) (which we’ve discussed before here!) is also related to another interest[ing] word: sequester.

To sequester comes from the Latin *sequestrare*, which means, “to put in safekeeping.” This, in turn, is from the earlier Latin, *sequester* “trustee, mediator.” The Latin *sequester*  is from the Latin *segui*, meaning, “to follow” — from which we also get the Spanish for the same, *seguir*.

In other words: Sequester went from meaning “to follow” to “being a trusted party” to “the trusted party holding something apart from everything else” to “holding something apart from everything else.” This is interesting because of the surprising implication of **trust** in the earlier connotations–but not the earliest connotations. Today, when you sequester someone or something, there is often a distinct lack of trust involved!

You can see the connection with *seguir* because the s-g of *seguir* maps to the s-qu of *sequester* easily!

Comment: The shift seems to come, as Cicero implies, when the Arbitrator is self-appointed. If the local 'boss' joins in a dispute between two poor people, the disputed car/ farm/ cash may never reach either of the disputants. The definition has shifted from "you are someone we trust;" to "I am someone you can trust,"

Comment: @Hugh Thank you for your comment and felicitations!